# Restricting values in XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an XSD with two elements, `name` and `color`. Would like to restrict length of names to 5. Getting an error:

> simpleType element not supported in this context.

As I understand these are custom types that can used in declaring elements in a schema file.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="fruits">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" />
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:name">
                            <xs:length="5">
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:/element>
                <xs:element name="color" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fruits 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="simplexsd2.xsd">
    <name>Apple</name>
</fruits>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among the multiple syntax errors to be fixed in your XSD are,

- prematurely closed `xs:element` element.
- malformed `xs:length` element.
- malformed close tags.

Here is your XSD updated to be well-formed and to support your intended validation of `name` elements to have string values restricted to length `5`:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="fruits">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:length value="5"/>
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="color" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```